# What is the difference between full_control and all ACL permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

The `s3cmd --help` indicates that the `--acl-grant` flag accepts a `full_control` as well as an `all` value:

```
--acl-grant=PERMISSION:EMAIL or USER_CANONICAL_ID
                       Grant stated permission to a given amazon user.
                       Permission is one of: read, write, read_acp,
                       write_acp, full_control, all
```

However, the [S3 Access Control Overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) does not list an `all` permission.  What is `all` and how is it different than `full_control`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a look in the source code, there doesn't seem to be any difference. If you set the permission to `all` it will normalize it to `full_control`

https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/blob/master/S3/ACL.py#L154